# How to parse xml response of soap php

Tags: php, soap, response

i need to parse this response of soapserver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <wsa:MessageID SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">uuid:5f7271f0-de19-11e1-8035-e656d1754971</wsa:MessageID>
  <wsa:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:wssigatewayResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">
   <ns1:result xsi:nil="true"/>
   <ttOut xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">
    <ttOutRow xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">
     <ParPos xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">0</ParPos>
     <ParNam xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">ContentType</ParNam>
     <ParVal xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">text/xml</ParVal>
    </ttOutRow>
    <ttOutRow xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">
     <ParPos xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">1</ParPos>
     <ParNam xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">Result</ParNam>
     <ParVal xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">200</ParVal>
    </ttOutRow>
    <ttOutRow xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">
     <ParPos xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">2</ParPos>
     <ParNam xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">XMLDocumentOut</ParNam>
     <ParVal xmlns="urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot; ?&gt;
&lt;DtsAgencyLoginResponse xmlns=&quot;DTS&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xsi:schemaLocation=&quot;DTS file:///R:/xsd/DtsAgencyLoginMessage_01.xsd&quot;&gt;&lt;SessionInfo&gt;&lt;SessionID&gt;178918&lt;/SessionID&gt;&lt;Profile&gt;A&lt;/Profile&gt;&lt;Language&gt;ENG&lt;/Language&gt;&lt;Version&gt;1&lt;/Version&gt;&lt;/SessionInfo&gt;&lt;AdvisoryInfo/&gt;&lt;/DtsAgencyLoginResponse&gt;</ParVal>
    </ttOutRow>
   </ttOut>
   <ns1:opcErrorMessage/>
  </ns1:wssigatewayResponse>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can i get SessionID from ParVal in the last ttOutRow?

Comment: 1st take a look at `Related` to the right of the webpage on how to parse that xml, then parse that XML, urldecode the last `ttOutRow` load the decoded string with simplexml_load_string and parse again to find session id. using regular expressions to get session id is way to difficult..

Comment: i try foreach($xml->ttOutRow as $ttout)
{
    echo $ttout['ParVal'];   
} but it doesn't enter in foreach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the SOAP response into an `DOMDocument` object:

```
$soapDoc = new DOMDocument();
$soapDoc->loadXML($soapResponse);
```

Prepare a `DOMXPath` object for that document:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($soapDoc);
```

Register a prefix for the `urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate` namespace:

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('operate', 'urn:it-progress-operate:ws_operate');
```

Retrieve the payload node:

```
$path = "//operate:ttOutRow[operate:ParNam='XMLDocumentOut']/operate:ParVal";
$result = $xpath->query($path);
```

Save the payload XML:

```
$payloadXML = $result->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Now that you have the payload XML string, go through the process again:

- Load it into a DOMDocument
- Prepare a DOMXpath object
- Register the `DTS` namespace
- Use XPath to retrieve the value

It's probably best to wrap the whole process into a function so you can re-use it.

Comment: the best question i've never seen! thanks!!! :)